# Ethers: invalid object key

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, ethers.js

I'm tryin send transaction via ethers, seems looks good, but has error...
Connections with wallet ok.
Code bellow:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
(async () => {

    prov2="provider url Alchemy"

    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(prov2);
    let wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic("my mnemonic")
    const signer = wallet.connect(provider)
    const gasPrice = provider.getGasPrice();

   let nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(
        wallet.address,
        "latest"
  );
   const recepient = "0x00000000006c3856cbEf3e08E8dF289169EdE581";
   let txn = {
        type: 2,
        chainId: 5,
        from: wallet.address, 
        to: recepient,
        value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.000001", "ether"),
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits("150","gwei"),
        maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits("170","gwei"),
        nonce: nonce
   };

    try {
        let signedTx = await signer.sendTransaction(txn)
    const receipt = await txn.wait();
    console.log(receipt);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.name)
        console.log(e.message)
    }

})();
```

And got: invalid object key error ....
I tried googling the error, but got nothing
[image]

What can it be?

Answer (score 3):

The error message says "object key error". I suspect that your transaction object.

```
let txn = {type: 2,...}
```

is not correct. I checked the https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/transactions/ and there is no `type` key property in the `transaction` object

Comment: thanks, i remove "type:" and change gas format, now working